# useState no rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone help me figure out how come when I change my state using ReactHooks its not rerendering my component

```
   const [newsCatalog, setNewsCatalog] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
     fetchNews();
    });

    const fetchNews = async () => {
      const GetAllNewArticleResults = await GetAllNewArticle();
      let promises = [];
            let tempNewsCatalog = newsCatalog;
            GetAllNewArticleResults.map(async e => {
              promises.push(
                await htmlToJson.parse(
                  e.HTMLNewsCode,
                  {
                    title: function($doc) {
                      return textTruncate($doc.find("H2").text(), 50);
                    },
                    link: function($doc) {
                      return $doc.find("A").attr("href");
                    },
                    content: function($doc) {
                      return textTruncate($doc.find("P").text(), 80);
                    },
                    imageURL: function($doc) {
                      return $doc.find("img").attr("src");
                    }
                  },
                  function(err, result) {
                    tempNewsCatalog.push({
                      ...result
                    });
                  }
                )
              );
              return null;
     });

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      setNewsCatalog(newsCatalog, ...tempNewsCatalog);    
    }); 
};


          return (
            <div className="container mb-4" id="News">
              <div className="h4 mb-3">OUR NEWS</div>
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap mw-90">
                {newsCatalog.length}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
```

When I tried running it, the just displays "0" in the "newsCatalog.length". But when I tried to inspect it, it already has items on it.

Comment: Please show the entire component. Currently you don't show where `setNewsCatalog` is defined.

Comment: Oops let me edit it in @RyanCogswell

Answer (score 1):

```
// helper method
function htmlToJson(htmlNewsCode) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   htmlToJson.parse(
     htmlNewsCode,
     {
       title: function($doc) { return textTruncate($doc.find("H2").text(), 50); },
       // implement your other methods
     },
     (err, result) => { 
       if (err) { 
        reject(err);
        return;
       }

       resolve(result)
     }
   )
 })
}


// your component
const [newsCatalog, setNewsCatalog] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {

 async function fetchNews() {
  // TODO: Implement error handling using try/catch
  const GetAllNewArticleResults = await GetAllNewArticle();
  const promises = GetAllNewArticleResults.map((e) => {
   return htmlToJson(e. HTMLNewsCode);
  })

  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  setNewsCatalog(prev => [...prev, ...results]);
 }

 fetchNews();

}, /* You probably need to specify the DEPS */)
```

Comment: Is this correct that the fetchNews function is inside the useEffect?

Comment: I personally think it is correct since that's the only place where it is used

Comment: I tried this out not sure why htmlToJson.parse() is throwing me errors.

Comment: does htmlToJson.parse return a promise?, I was assuming that it was a callback based function, that's why I created htmlToJson (it wraps htmlToJson.parse into a promise, so you can use async and await)

Comment: It seems like a promise hmmm

Comment: Whats DEPS by the way?

Comment: the dependencies that define where the effect should be run or not (if you do not provide any, your effect will run n million times, you do not want that because you will be hitting someone else server a lot)

Comment: Thanks for this I was able to make it work with a slight changes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `Promise.all` call failed, and issue is with this code

```
tempNewsCatalog.push({
   ...result
});
```

It is pushing to `newsCatalog`. Because it is object and connect by pointer with `tempNewsCatalog`. So you have values, but no rerender.

try instead to create epmty array, and push it there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for AngelSalazar I tried changing my code

```
const [newsCatalog, setNewsCatalog] = useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchNews() {
          // TODO: Implement error handling using try/catch
    const GetAllNewArticleResults = await GetAllNewArticle();
    let promises = [];

    GetAllNewArticleResults.map(e => {
      promises.push(
        htmlToJson.parse(
                e.HTMLNewsCode,
                {
                  title: function($doc) {
                    return textTruncate($doc.find("H2").text(), 50);
                  },
                  link: function($doc) {
                    return $doc.find("A").attr("href");
                  },
                  content: function($doc) {
                    return textTruncate($doc.find("P").text(), 80);
                  },
                  imageURL: function($doc) {
                    return $doc.find("img").attr("src");
                  }
                },
                function(err, result) {
                  return result;
                }
              )
            );
          });

          const results = await Promise.all(promises);
          setNewsCatalog(prev => [...prev, ...results]);
     }

   fetchNews();
 }, []);
```